# Neighbour from "hell"

Tags: personal-practice, ethics

Imagine you live in an urban area, have a job, you have to sleep well so that your mind is well rested.

Your neighbour doesnt work, he gets government money help. The problem is that when night arrives, he drugs himself, listen music in the most higher bass and volume at 4 in the morning. You call him attention, he continues to do the same.

If you call the police, probably it will develop a further problem with that neighbour and end up in a violent answer from him.

According to Buddhism, how can one deal with such a situation in a skillful manner?

Answer (score 3):

Show your kindness (compassion), with Buddhist wisdom ;)

... for ur particular case, buy ur neigbhour a set of headphone in supreme quality, with a note inserted e.g.: *my favourite brand, cool stuff. Enjoy music any time, day & night, dusk till dawn!*

You may knock on the door to hand it to him, or send by mail. Remember, wrap it in nice gift paper, sign your name, with smile. Consider, the cost to move or cost of time to deal with engaging police/third party, this gift is tiny.

And surely you will then hv a neighbour who will let u stayed in raining day when u forgot ur key waiting for the locksmith... 囧

Comment: I liked your suggestion, and appreciate your kindness. But i think wouldnt work. Either way is too late, i moved. Was just curious about what can i possibly done if i had more energy and patience.

Comment: @nm85 dang you moved fast...

Answer (score 2):

Three options: (i) advise your neighbour in a very kind & gentle manner; if this fails; (ii) contact legal authorities; if this fails; (iii) move.

Answer (score 1):

Same but slightly different issue here. Can't tell which apartment the music comes from because it is so loud. Starts between 4AM and ends as late as 1AM.

Can often meditate despite the sound. One time however the "music" was so loud there was no concentration to be had. Then had to remember the words of, I believe, Ajahn Chah, who reminds that is not the noise bothering us but it is us bothering the noise.

Didn't help the meditation then, but did provide some insights. Now the sound doesn't bother so much. I sleep better. Meditate better, often despite the decibel.

Perhaps contemplation on sound might be beneficial in any quiet time that arises. Metta Meditation couldn't hurt either if nothing more than to soften your heart and mind.